# how to provide a custom component with specific functions

Tags: angular

I have a custom table with action buttons. I would like these buttons actions to trigger specific actions in the custom component.
Unfortunately I can't find any clean way to provide my custom table with functions, especially functions that use the attributes of my custom table. [here is the table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-frlhfb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html), [the customized table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-frlhfb?file=src%2Fapp%2Froles-list%2Froles-list.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

I see you have an `rolesListService` injected to root, so I am going to use that to receive info what user has clicked on.

```html
 <mat-menu #matMenu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="onEditRow('rules')">
        <span>rules</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="onEditRow('configure')">
        <span>configure</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="onEditRow('notifications')">
        <span>notifications</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-roles-list',
  templateUrl: './roles-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./roles-list.component.css'],
})
export class RolesListComponent implements OnInit {

  onEditRow(action: string) {
    this.roleListService.onClickAction.next(action)
  }

}
```

Service will hold the latest action and emit this to all subscribers.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RolesListService {

  onClickAction = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
  constructor() {}

}
```

RolesPaneComponent will subscribe to it and use it.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-roles-pane',
  templateUrl: './roles-pane.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./roles-pane.component.css']
})
export class RolesPaneComponent implements OnInit {

  userClickedAction$: Observable<any> | undefined;

  constructor(private roleListService: RolesListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userClickedAction$ = this.roleListService.onClickAction.pipe(data => {return data;})
  }

}
```

```html
I am roles panel, I have recieved info that user clicked: {{userClickedAction$ | async}}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etcip4?file=src%2Fapp%2Froles-pane%2Froles-pane.component.html